# Sencha Touch 2 pie chart has no labels

Tags: sencha-touch-2, pie-chart, label

I am attempting to follow [this](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.3.0/#!/api/Ext.chart.series.Pie) example for creating a pie chart but my chart does not display labels for the sections. I copied and used the exact code from the example linked above.

The chart display complete with color sections but there are no labels like in the example.

My code is pasted below:

```
    Ext.define('RevivalTimes.view.Chart', {
        extend: 'Ext.chart.PolarChart',
        xtype: 'chart',

        requires: [
            'Ext.chart.series.Pie',
            'Ext.chart.interactions.Rotate'
        ],

        config: {
            title: 'Statistics',
            iconCls: 'settings',

            layout: 'fit',

            animate: true,
            interactions: ['rotate'],
            colors: ['#115fa6', '#94ae0a', '#a61120', '#ff8809', '#ffd13e'],
            store: {
              fields: ['name', 'data1', 'data2', 'data3', 'data4', 'data5'],
              data: [
                  {name: 'metric one',   data1: 10, data2: 12, data3: 14, data4: 8,  data5: 13},
                  {name: 'metric two',   data1: 7,  data2: 8,  data3: 16, data4: 10, data5: 3},
                  {name: 'metric three', data1: 5,  data2: 2,  data3: 14, data4: 12, data5: 7},
                  {name: 'metric four',  data1: 2,  data2: 14, data3: 6,  data4: 1,  data5: 23},
                  {name: 'metric five',  data1: 27, data2: 38, data3: 36, data4: 13, data5: 33}
              ]
            },
            series: [{
                type: 'pie',
                label: {
                    field: 'name',
                    display: 'rotate'
                },
                xField: 'data3',
                donut: 30
            }]

        } //config
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The labels show with the inclusion of labelField as shown in the code below:

```
series: [{
    type: 'pie',
    label: {
        field: 'name',
        display: 'rotate'
    },
    xField: 'data1',
    donut: 30,

    labelField: 'name',
    showInLegend: true,
}],
```